# excel 2007 Windows 7 - graphs stopped working

Tags: excel, windows-7, excel-2007

I was in Excel 2007, working on an .xls file, not .xlsx.

When I tried to do a print preview, it told me to convert the file to .xlsx.

I did this and got some errors about named ranges.  I accepted all notifications and the file converted.

After the file converted, all my graphs and charts stopped working.

I opened the old file - same thing....the charts tabs just show solid gray on the page and no chart.

I closed the program, restarted, and check again....same deal, plus ALL my excel files appear to have the same problem of missing charts/graphs.

I recall the error notification telling me that there were named ranges that don't exist and something about having to do something in VBA, but I sort of ignored it because I thought it was just related to that file.

This was all 100% triggered by converting 1 file from xls to xlsx.

What the heck happened?  Please help!!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this very strange problem.

I loaded the Office Disk again thinking I might reintall office or reinsall excel.  There was an option for 'Repair Office'.

I ran the repair, which took about 10 minutes, then rebooted the machine.

Everything seems to be back to normal now.

Very weird.

Comment: Yes, strange behavior, but these things happen. You might as well mark your answer as correct.